# I have an array with same values need to remove all the other values

Tags: angular, typescript

for eg:

```
var arr = {
    "servicegroup": [{
            "name": "yy",
            "description": "yy",
            "isvalid": 1
        }, {
            "name": "yy",
            "description": "yy",
            "isvalid": 1]
    }
}
```

Comment: By which key in the array you are finding the unique element?

Comment: need to check same name or not

Comment: This is not valid js - parentheses do not match. Please post valid input and desired output. What have you tried to solve the problem?

Comment: edited the input

Comment: your js is still invalid.. your array ends before its last element

Comment: yes..can you help me to find a solution in this var arr = {
    "servicegroup": [{
            "name": "yy",
            "description": "yy",
            "isvalid": 1
        }, {
            "name": "yy",
            "description": "yy",
            "isvalid": 1
    }]
}

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include any additional information you have to your question. Avoid adding this in the comments, as they are harder to read and can be deleted easier. The edit button for your post is just below the post's tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of the splice-functionality of the arrays and remove unwanted elements:

Something like this:

```js
var arr = {
  "servicegroup": [{
    "name": "yy",
    "description": "yy",
    "isvalid": 1
  }, {
    "name": "yy",
    "description": "yy",
    "isvalid": 1
  }]
}

console.log('Original Array ==>', arr);

for (let i = 1; i < arr.servicegroup.length; i++) {
  let stringifiedFirstObject = JSON.stringify(arr.servicegroup[0]);

  let stringifiedIthObj = JSON.stringify(arr.servicegroup[i]);

  if (stringifiedFirstObject === stringifiedIthObj) {
    arr.servicegroup.splice(i, 1);
  }
}

console.log('Modified Array ==>', arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

The Algorithmic Way :-

```js
const arr = { "servicegroup": [ { "name": "yy", "description": "yy", "isvalid": 1 }, { "name": "yy", "description": "yy", "isvalid": 2 } ] };
const source = arr[ 'servicegroup' ];
const obj = {};
const res = [];
let i = 0;
let count = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < source.length; i++) {
    const el = source[ i ];
    if (count === 0) {
        obj[ el.name ] = true;
        *emphasized text*count++;
    }
    if (obj[ el.name ]) {
        res.push(el);
        delete obj[ el.name ];
    }
}
console.log(res);
```